# LeafletMap is showing error even after importing the leaflet package in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I was working on a covid application which shows covid mortality rate during all the three waves, particularly for my country ***India***, but here the issue is while I'm trying to use leaflet package, its showing an error

```js
import React from "react";
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./Map.css";
import { showDataOnMap } from "./util";

function Map({ countries, casesType, center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <LeafletMap center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        {showDataOnMap(countries, casesType)}
      </LeafletMap>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

this package name: Map.js

even I had run the cmd in the terminal which imports the leaflet: `npm i react-leaflet`, but it is still showing error, please help anyone

This is localhost error which it is showing

[image]

Comment: With React Leflet version 2, you indeed import `Map`. But looks like you use version 3, which now provides `MapContainer` instead, among other modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code snippet to import Map.
It will surely work:

```
import { MapContainer as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet"
```

We need to import the content as it is from the dependencies. So, when the dependencies are updated this problem can occur, so you need to check what you have imported.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're trying to export function Map which has the same name as Map you assigned to LeafletMap, try to change your function name, for instance

```
import React from "react";
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./Map.css";
import { showDataOnMap } from "./util";

function NewMap({ countries, casesType, center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <LeafletMap center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        {showDataOnMap(countries, casesType)}
      </LeafletMap>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewMap;
```

Comment: if i export NewMap then in that case, it is throwing NewMap keyword error

Comment: Maybe you can share the kind of error, you get when you change function name

Comment: `Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/Map.js 19:35-45

export 'Map' (imported as 'LeafletMap') was not found in 'react-leaflet' (possible exports: AttributionControl, Circle, CircleMarker, FeatureGroup, GeoJSON, ImageOverlay, LayerGroup, LayersControl, MapConsumer, MapContainer, Marker, Pane, Polygon, Polyline, Popup, Rectangle, SVGOverlay, ScaleControl, TileLayer, Tooltip, VideoOverlay, WMSTileLayer, ZoomControl, useMap, useMapEvent, useMapEvents)

`

Comment: delete package-lock.json file  and run npm install again

Comment: More explanation about above comment, sometimes when you try to change your source code and the same error still exist, this can depend on the package-lock.json File which cached previous source code, and what you can do is to delete the file and reinstall again